# ¿Cómo se están añadiendo aquí los datos al array?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, condiciones, scope

Este es un problema de bucles e iteración básico. Y no entiendo como va metiendo datos al array alumnosTotales = []. Primero en el for, etc.

Problema:

- Crear mini sistemas que nos permita registrar los alumnos que están presentes (P)
  y ausentes (A) en clase.
- Pasados los 30 días mostrar la situación final de todos los alumnos (total de p y a)
- Se puede tener un máximo de 10% de ausencias por semestre, si se tienen mas aclarar que esta reprobado.

```
    let cantidad = prompt("¿Cuantos alumnos son?");
    let alumnosTotales = [];
    
    
    for (let i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
        alumnosTotales[i] = [prompt("nombre del alumno " + (i+1)), 0];
    }
    
    
    const tomarAsistencia = (alumno,p)=>{
        let presencia = prompt(nombre);
        if (presencia == "p" || presencia == "P") {
            alumnosTotales[p][1]++;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        for (alumno in alumnosTotales) {
            tomarAsistencia(alumnosTotales[alumno][0],alumno)
        }
    }
    for (alumno in alumnosTotales){
        let resultado = `${alumnosTotales[alumno][0]}:<br>
        ___________Asistencias: ${alumnosTotales[alumno][1]}<br>
        ___________Ausencias: ${30 - alumnosTotales[alumno][1]}`;
    
        if (30 - alumnosTotales[alumno][1] > 18){
            resultado+= "REPROBADO POR INASISTENCIAS<br><br>" 
        }
            else {
                resultado+= "<br><br>"
            }
        document.write(resultado);
    }
```

aca dejo el codigo en github, mas legible: https://github.com/soydalto/curso-de-javascript/blob/main/capitulo%202/problema%202/codigo.js

Me gustaria saber esto, para poder ver qué tema en especifico debo repasar, porque estoy medio perdido. Busque documentaciones de arrays, scopes, for. Pero en ninguna explica esta forma de usarlos. O talvez estoy usando mal la lógica.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El codigo se puede poner legible aca.. no hay necesidad de compartir tu git, que puede desaparecer o cambiar ;)

Comment: Cual es la parte que no entendes?

Comment: La parte que no entiendo es cuando escribe  dentro del primer for alumnosTotales[i], esta creando desde el for, un array dentro de alumnosTotales no?

Comment: exactamente.. esta haciendo lo que pensas...

Comment: Una forma de comprobar el orden es usar un console.log(alumnosTotales) cuando acabes de meter los alumnos en el array, esto te va a devolver los alumnos que tu has metido, no se si esa es tu duda